# Is there a reason to specify shifts from 8-bit registers?

Tags: assembly, x86

Is there a reason why one should specify shifts using the 8-bit registers rather than a 32-bit register? I have seen x86 code a few times that looks like this:

```
movl %ebx, %ecx
sall %cl,  %edx
```

Since this only uses the low 8 bits of `ecx`, I would translate this to something like (in C code):

```
ebx = ecx;
edx = edx << (ecx % 256);
```

Where it seems it would just be easier to say:

```
movl %ebx, %ecx
sall %ecx, %edx
```

I've seen the 8-bit register used even in places like documentation, where the difference between `cl` and `ecx` wouldn't make a difference for the correctness of a code example. For example at [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19620-01/805-4693/instructionset-27/index.html).

Comment: As it shows on the web page you linked to, the `sall %ecx, %edx` instruction simply does not exist. The first parameter to `sall` must be `%cl` or an 8-bit immediate.

Comment: since it doesn't make sense to shift a 32bit register more than 32 times, why choose a register with a range of 0-4 billion ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the x86 architecture, you can only shift and rotate by 1, an immediate value, or the register `cl`. No other possibilities are encodable. Thus all code that shifts by a variable amount invariably uses the `cl` register for the shift amount. `cl` was picked because the shift amount never needs to be more than the size of a general purpose register (16 back then).

Comment: I had no idea! I assumed that the documentation just used `%cl` as an example. Thanks!

Comment: Historical trivia - the original 8088 / 8086 would shift up to 255 times despite the register size. In later processors, the shift count is masked, and one of the side effects is you can't shift a 32 bit register by 32 or a 64 bit register by 64 (which would zero them out, but in some cases that could be a desired effect).

Comment: @David You are reading reference material. It's not a tutorial. If any register were permitted, it would have said so (e.g. by saying `reg32`).