# Which assembly instructions or scenarios explicitly require the use of the RCX, ECX, CX, or CL counter registers?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, masm, calling-convention

After reading this question [Why is %cl the only register the sal-operation will accept as a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69634484/why-is-cl-the-only-register-the-sal-operation-will-accept-as-a-parameter), I'm curious about what other instructions require the count register?

**Loop Control**

The LOOP instructions assume that the CX, ECX, or RCX register contains the loop count.

```
loop
loopnz
loopne
loopz
loope
```

**Jumps**

Jump instructions that perform a jump if the CX, ECX, or RCX register is zero.

```
jcxz
jecxz
jrcxz
```

**Repeat Prefixes**

These repeat prefixes are used with string instructions and use the count register.

```
rep
repe
repz
repne
repnz
```

**Bit Shifting**

Logical, Shift, Rotate and Bit Instructions (omitted dword and qword variants such as shld, shlq, ...)

```
shl
shr
sal
sar
rol
ror
rcl
rcr
```

**Fastcall Calling Convention**

The first two DWORD or smaller arguments that are found in the argument list from left to right are passed in `ECX` and EDX registers; all other arguments are passed on the stack from right to left.

```
__attribute__((fastcall)) void printnums(int num1, int num2, int num3){
    printf("The numbers you sent are: %d %d %d", num1, num2, num3);
}

int main(){
    printnums(1, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

**Microsoft x64 calling convention**

In the Microsoft x64 calling convention, the first four integer or pointer arguments are passed to a function in the `RCX`, RDX, R8, and R9 registers. If there are more than four arguments, the remaining arguments are passed on the stack.

**System V AMD64 ABI**

The first six integer or pointer arguments are passed in registers RDI, RSI, RDX, `RCX`, R8, R9.

**Question**

Are there other scenarios which require the use of the counter register?

Would the best place to check be the [Combined Volume Set of Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manuals](https://cdrdv2.intel.com/v1/dl/getContent/671200)?

Comment: Various other instructions operate on fixed registers, including e.g. the `cpuid` instruction.  I don't think there is a complete list anywhere.

Comment: Obsolete instruction [IBTS](https://www.pcjs.org/documents/manuals/intel/80386/ibts_xbts/)

Comment: I think these use xcx "implicitly" rather than "explicitly" — implicitly meaning encoded within the opcode operation rather than being specifically (explicitly) named as a register source/target.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search for "CX" and "CL" in http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html / http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html since they have a column for implicit operands.

**The implicit uses or rCX you already mentioned:**

- variable count shifts/rotates / shrd/shld (other than BMI2 `shlx` etc.)
- `j*cxz` / `loop` / `loop[n]e`
- `rep` / `rep[n]e` string ops

**Other implicit uses or rCX:**

- [`cpuid`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cpuid) - an input (EAX=leaf, ECX=sub leaf for some EAX values) as well as output
- [`xgetbv`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xgetbv) / `xsetbv` (extended control register access, e.g. for checking of the OS enabled AVX)
- SSE4.2 [`pcmpistri`](https://www.strchr.com/strcmp_and_strlen_using_sse_4.2) / `pcmpestri` - index of first match
- [`monitor`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/monitor)/[`mwait`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mwait) (power-management extensions)
- `rdmsr` / [`wrmsr`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/wrmsr) (MSR number)
- [`rdtscp`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rdtscp) (Processor ID output)
- non-64-bit-mode `pusha`/`popa` (along with all other legacy regs)
- [`syscall`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/syscall) (written with user-space RIP so the kernel can return)

That search of the coder32 and coder64 tables missed the following because rCX is part of `...`:

- [`cmpxchg16b`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmpxchg8b:cmpxchg16b) - part of the RCX:RBX input.  (RDX:RAX is the other non-memory input).  Same for `cmpxchg8b` with ECX.
- Possibly others that I'm not thinking of.

And what you already mentioned:

- Standard calling conventions

---

Related: *[Why are RBP and RSP called general-purpose registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529449/why-are-rbp-and-rsp-called-general-purpose-registers)* - there are implicit uses for almost every register, except for some of r8-r15.